# Window not close after auth hybridauth v3

Tags: php, hybridauth, hybridauthprovider

I installed the Hybridauth V3 and work correctly. 
My test was on google (example 7)and works fine but the popup doesn't want to close.

How can i fix the problem from the callback script or Google for example to close the window ?

My html file

```
<script>
        function auth_popup( provider ){
            var authWindow = window.open('<?php echo $Hybrid->getCallBackUrl(); ?>?provider='+provider, 'authWindow', 'width=600,height=400, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, copyhistory=no');
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

callback.php

```
 echo "
        <script>
            window.opener.location.reload();
            window.close();
        </script>";
```